# How to split a string in r of a txt file with lots of letters without spacing?

Tags: r, stringr

Let say I have a txt file look like this

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaadddddddddddddssssssssssbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccxxxxxxxxxxsddddddaaasdadvvvvvvvvbbbbbbbaxxxxnnnnnnnnnwwwwwwwwwwwwww
```

How do I apply `str_split()` in this case?

I am trying to calculate how many letter "a" has show up in this txt file

This what I have so far,

```r
str_split(mytxtfile, "")
```

then I ran `str_length(str_detect(mytxtfile, "a"))`

The function came out with less than 9 and I believed I did something wrong when I using `str_split()`

Please help!

Answer (score 6):

base R option using `lengths` with `regmatches` and `gregexpr` to count your character in a string like this:

```r
input = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaadddddddddddddssssssssssbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccxxxxxxxxxxsddddddaaasdadvvvvvvvvbbbbbbbaxxxxnnnnnnnnnwwwwwwwwwwwwww'
lengths(regmatches(input, gregexpr("a", input)))
#> [1] 21
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

@jay.sf is right! `regmatches` is not necessary:

```r
input = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaadddddddddddddssssssssssbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccxxxxxxxxxxsddddddaaasdadvvvvvvvvbbbbbbbaxxxxnnnnnnnnnwwwwwwwwwwwwww'
lengths(gregexpr("a", input))
#> [1] 21
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Why the `regmatches`, `lengths(gregexpr('a', x))` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `str_count` to count inside of a string:

```r
library(stringr)
mytxtfile = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaadddddddddddddssssssssssbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccxxxxxxxxxxsddddddaaasdadvvvvvvvvbbbbbbbaxxxxnnnnnnnnnwwwwwwwwwwwwww"
str_count(mytxtfile, "a")
#[1] 21
```

---

Using `str_split_*` functions, you can use `str_split_1` (`stringr 1.5.0` required) + `str_detect` + `sum` (although as you see it `str_count` is much better):

```r
str_split_1(mytxtfile, "") |>
  str_detect("a") |>
  sum()
#[1] 21
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the options, removing all but a's and counting the chars:

```r
nchar(gsub("[^a]", "", mytxtfile))
```

Output:

```
[1] 21
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to count the number of times a character is repeated in sequence **not just for one character but for all characters in the string**, here's a `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(strng) %>%
  mutate(
    # 1. split `strng` any time next char is not the same as prior char:
    sameChar = str_split(strng, "(?<=(.))(?!\\1|$)"),
    # 2. count number of chars in each element of list:
    sameCharN = lapply(sameChar, function(x) nchar(x)))
    strng
1 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaadddddddddddddssssssssssbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccxxxxxxxxxxsddddddaaasdadvvvvvvvvbbbbbbbaxxxxnnnnnnnnnwwwwwwwwwwwwww
                                                                                                                                                               sameChar
1 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, ddddddddddddd, ssssssssss, bbbbbbbbbbbbb, cccccccccc, xxxxxxxxxx, s, dddddd, aaa, s, d, a, d, vvvvvvvv, bbbbbbb, a, xxxx, nnnnnnnnn, wwwwwwwwwwwwww
                                                       sameCharN
1 16, 13, 10, 13, 10, 10, 1, 6, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 7, 1, 4, 9, 14
```

Here's how the `str_split` regex works:

- `(?<=(.))`: positive look-behind defining any character (`.`) occurring to the left of the split point as a capture group (in parentheses)
- `(?!\\1|$)`: postive look-ahead asserting that the split must not (`!`) be performed if the immediately next char is the same (`\\1`) as the char immediately prior OR (`|`) the final position in the string

Data:

```
strng <- "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaadddddddddddddssssssssssbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccxxxxxxxxxxsddddddaaasdadvvvvvvvvbbbbbbbaxxxxnnnnnnnnnwwwwwwwwwwwwww"
```

Comment: You could in base R do `table(strsplit(strng, ""))`